# find count jobs and applied member mysql

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables

```
job
id job_name
1  php
2  python
3  ROR


applied_user
id job_id user_id
1  2      4
2  2      5
3  2      5
4  1      54
```

Now i want count how many jobs and applied member with single query

```
jobs applied_user
3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you # of unique jobs and # of unique users applied

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT job_id) as jobs, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as applied_user
FROM
  applied_user
```